# Mongo php extension after Heroku update (composer)

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku, composer-php, php-extension

I have days trying everything and looking everywhere the solution.

The problem happened when **Heroku** sent me an email about an update which required **Composer** for **PHP** aplications.

**My folder currently:**

```
-- MyProject/
------ ext/
---------- mongo.so
------ php.ini
------ composer.json
------ index.php
```

(Before the problem, this running perfect of course without *Composer*).

**php.ini**

```
extension_dir = "/app/www/ext/"
extension=mongo.so
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-mongo": "*"
  }
}
```

Obviously if I run the *install command*, I get error:

```
$ composer install

  Problem 1
     - The requested PHP extension ext-mongo * is missing from your system.
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
$connection = new Mongo("mongodb://username:password@ds053728.mongolab.com:53728/dbname");
$db = $connection->dbname;
echo "done?";
?>
```

Heroku apparently no longer recognizes the *php.ini* settings and *ext/mongo.so*, so I get errors like **Mongo Class not found**.

I'm also not sure how to add the extensions ("*ext-....*") with *composer* that do not appear in https://packagist.org/

I can't find the solution with this information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Comment: I've seen that you created a mongo package in packagist, did it work? I'm trying to fix something similar, I used to install mongo.so using pecl in a shell script, but now the shell script doesn't run so the extension doesn't get loaded.

Comment: No, I do not think it works that way according to documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongo` extension is now supported: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/467
 - no need for custom buildpacks.

Comment: Great! .. I was expecting this news. It is true that the files (images) uploaded to heroku are not permanent, is there any trick?

Comment: That is true. What if you run two servers? Three? How do you make sure they're available on all? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem