# How do I enable MongoDB for PHP on Heroku apps

Tags: php, mongodb, heroku

I've looked quite a bit and have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450396/mongo-php-extension-after-heroku-update-composer), and the corresponding notice that extension is [now available](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/467).  However with the ext, and dropping the ext I still get errors.

Also in their documentation updated 12/3/2014 the ext is in the example at [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions).

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested package mongo could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

When I try to run my application I see the error in the log that `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found`

What am i doing incorrectly?

Comment: To clarify the solution.  As dzuelke mentioned, I needed to install the MongoDB extension locally. After doing the composer install worked correctly and was able to find the required mongo stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question. The error messages you provided give little information in the context.

You add

```
"ext-mongo": "*"
```

to the `require { ... }` section in your `composer.json`.

After that, run

```
$ composer update
```

to re-generate `composer.lock`, then

```
$ git add composer.json composer.lock
$ git commit -m "enable ext/mongo"
$ git push heroku master
```

That's all.

Comment: I'd started with the sample project via the heroku github account.  From that I'd modified it to use mongo. I've uploaded a screenshot to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzn7bwoqp34ux88/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-06%20at%204.19.45%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Yeah, you need the MongoDB extension installed locally - you're gonna do development etc on your local computer as well, no? http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity :) `pecl install mongo` or `brew install php55-mongo` or whatever other way you have, depending on how you installed (or not) PHP.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using PHP 7 you should **ext-mongodb** and not ext-mongo add to your composer.json

```
"ext-mongodb": "*"
```

After that make sure running

```
composer update
```

And committing your composer.lock since Heroku uses the composer.lock to enable the extensions.

Comment: `ext-mongodb` is the right name (PHP 8.x): https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/#installation